# XlsSaveOptions(SaveFormat.Excel97To2003) issue in IE 8

Tags: asp.net-mvc, aspose, aspose-cells

I am generating a report in an MVC project. The user has the option of getting the report in either .pdf format or .xls

I am using Aspose.Cells for the Excel file generation. The ActionResult method below is called.

```
    [HttpGet]
    public ActionResult GenerateReport(string format, string filterDate = "")
    {
      //Processing occurs here to get the appropriate info from Db.
      var fileFormat   = format.ToUpper() == "PDF" ? Format.Pdf : Format.Csv;
      var contentType  = fileFormat == Format.Pdf ? "application/pdf" : "application/vnd.ms-excel";
      var makePdf      = fileFormat == Format.Pdf;
      var fileContents = register.GetReport(makePdf, filterDate);

      return File(fileContents, contentType, "Report");
    }
```

register.GetReport() merely determines if GetExcelVersion() or GetPdfVersion() is called.

```
    private void GetExcelVersion(MemoryStream stream, string name, string dateRequested = "")
    {

      var license = new Aspose.Cells.License();
      license.SetLicense("Aspose.Total.lic");
      var workbook = new Workbook();
      var worksheet = workbook.Worksheets[0];
      var cells = worksheet.Cells;
      //writes out the appropriate information to the excel spreadsheet here           

      workbook.Save(stream, new XlsSaveOptions(Aspose.Cells.SaveFormat.Excel97To2003));
     }
```

This works a charm in Firefox and IE10 but when testing on IE8 I receive the following alert from Excel:-

The File you are trying to open 'XXXXX', is in a different format than specified by the file extension. Verify that the file is not corrupted and is from a trusted source before opening the file. Do you want to open the file now? Yes/No

Any ideas on what I am doing wrong?

Cheers!

Comment: Does Excel eventually open the file after giving the warning message? And is the MS Office version same on IE8 and IE10 machines?

Comment: Saqib - if you click on the yes prompt then the file opens up in Excel. The MS Office version is the same that is opening up both of using IE8 and IE10

Comment: It seems an issue with IE8, many such issues come in Google search results. Could you please try turning off the compatibility mode, as suggested at http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/ie/forum/ie8-windows_7/on-clicking-csv-file-link-file-opening-in-internet/fcf60b32-4fc7-43ac-afb8-49ba90fb322e?page=2

Comment: Worked a treat. Many thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As Saqib Razzaq mentioned in the comments above. Turn off compatibility mode as mentioned [here](http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/ie/forum/ie8-windows_7/on-clicking-csv-file-link-file-opening-in-internet/fcf60b32-4fc7-43ac-afb8-49ba90fb322e?page=2)